# What is "recorded" relationship in a class diagram?

Tags: design, object-oriented, uml

> Composite aggregates Part, Container contains Content, and Recorder records. Recorded are all very common relationships between classes in a class diagram. Creator suggests that the enclosing container or recorder class is a good candidate for the responsibility of creating the thing contained or recorded. Of course, this is only a guideline.

From the book: http://authors.phptr.com/larman/uml_ooad/index.html

What is this recorder? Any example would be appreciated.

Comment: That quote makes no sense to me.

Comment: Without more context, I'm not sure that this is answerable. Are there any diagrams or figures associated with this text? Is this part of a larger section where these terms are used in some kind of specific context?

Comment: @ThomasOwens Sorry this is the context. There is wikipedia page on this too. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29#Creator and it references the same book, and it also doesn't have more context to it.

Comment: I think there is more context somewhere. This quote, by itself, without more surrounding information, doesn't make sense. One sentence is "Recorded are all very common relationships in a class diagram." Recorded where? A table or figure? A diagram? If it's a diagram, what does the diagram look like? If it's a table, what other things are in that table that could be helpful.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that this book is trying to teach you a design methodology. Unless someone understands that particular design methodology, it will be hard to answer your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not well-versed in [the GRASP object-oriented design methodology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)), but I read through the Wikipedia article as well a some slide decks ([1](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~kena/classes/5448/f12/presentation-materials/rao.pdf), [2](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aldrich/214/slides/design-grasp.pdf)) about the approach. This is my understanding.

One of the "patterns" in GRASP is the Creator Pattern. This isn't a design pattern in the sense of the [Gang of Four patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) or Fowler's Patterns of Enterprise Architecture and so on. It's more of a principle or pattern. GRASP focuses on how you determine the responsibilities of a particular class in your object-oriented system.

A class that is a Creator means that it builds instances of other classes. There are different contexts for creation. In a composition or aggregation relationship, the parent *may* be responsible for creating the parts. In classes that record data, the class that records the data (for example, reading data from files or from user input or from databases) *may* be responsible for creating domain elements.

What this quoted paragraph is saying is, to the best of my knowledge, if you have a class that contains elements or records data, than you can consider having that class create the objects that represent its elements or data that is recorded.

Note that this is just guidance, though. Something to consider when working through your design. It's not a rule that must always be applied.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is some poor grammar and incorrect punctuation going on here. My best guess is that it should read as follows:

> The following [generic examples] are all very common relationships between classes in a class diagram:
>
> - `Composite` aggregates `Part`
> - `Container` contains `Content`
> - `Recorder` records `Recorded`
>
> [The] creator [some person introduced before this quotation] suggests that the enclosing `Container` or `Recorder` class is a good candidate for the responsibility of creating the thing contained or recorded [the `Content` and `Recorded` classes respectively, in the above examples]. Of course, this is only a guideline.

Text in square brackets is fully my own supposition, the rest is merely rearranged and differently punctuated.

If my guesswork is correct, then the Recorder is merely a generic and not particularly meaningful example of a class that could have some relationship to another class.

More tangible, real-world examples might be:

- `Company` employs `Employee`
- `Doctor` treats `Patient`
- `Shipment` contains `Order Item`

If the text had used these examples, you probably wouldn't have been asking about the meaning or significance of the term Doctor!